# nvm install nodejs onto raspberry pi via ssh erroring

Tags: node.js, ssh, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi2

I am trying to download ARM version of node 14 for a Raspberry Pi via NVM and SSH (from my mac).

My Raspberry Pi is `Raspberry Pi 2 Model B+ V1.2 2014`

I have a 64GB SD card.

Architecture returns:

```
lharby@raspberrypi:/usr/bin $ uname -m
armv6l
```

I managed to download and install nvm:

```
lharby@raspberrypi:~/Downloads $ nvm --version
0.33.11
```

Then I tried `nvm install 14`. I am assuming I don't need to pass any arguments or flags to this and it will know the target architecture.

I have tried doing this directly on the Pi and via SSH. It takes hours, and I finally get this error at the end of the console:

```
v14.21.2/files/out/Release/obj.target/icudata/gen/icudt70_dat.o /home/lharby/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v14.21.2/files/out/Release/obj/gen/icudt70_dat.S '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DNODE_OPENSSL_CONF_NAME=nodejs_conf' '-D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS' '-DOPENSSL_NO_PINSHARED' '-DOPENSSL_THREADS' '-DU_ATTRIBUTE_DEPRECATED=' '-D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE=' '-DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION=1' '-DUCONFIG_NO_SERVICE=1' '-DU_ENABLE_DYLOAD=0' '-DU_HAVE_STD_STRING=1' '-DUCONFIG_NO_BREAK_ITERATION=0' -I../deps/icu-small/source/common  -pthread -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-deprecated-declarations -Wno-strict-aliasing -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer  -MMD -MF /home/lharby/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v14.21.2/files/out/Release/.deps//home/lharby/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v14.21.2/files/out/Release/obj.target/icudata/gen/icudt70_dat.o.d.raw   -c
cc: fatal error: Killed signal terminated program cc1
compilation terminated.
make[1]: *** [tools/icu/icudata.target.mk:153: /home/lharby/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v14.21.2/files/out/Release/obj.target/icudata/gen/icudt70_dat.o] Error 1
make: *** [Makefile:109: node] Error 2
nvm: install v14.21.2 failed!
```

If I run `nvm ls` I get this:

```
lharby@raspberrypi:/usr/bin $
nvm ls
               
->       system
node -> stable (-> N/A) (default)
iojs -> N/A (default)
lts/* -> lts/hydrogen (-> N/A)
lts/argon -> v4.9.1 (-> N/A)
lts/boron -> v6.17.1 (-> N/A)
lts/carbon -> v8.17.0 (-> N/A)
lts/dubnium -> v10.24.1 (-> N/A)
lts/erbium -> v12.22.12 (-> N/A)
lts/fermium -> v14.21.2 (-> N/A)
lts/gallium -> v16.19.0 (-> N/A)
lts/hydrogen -> v18.12.1 (-> N/A)
```

I have also tried this argument:

`sudo apt-get install -y node npm`

Aswell as manually downloading the specific version for the Pi

`lharby@raspberrypi:~/Downloads $ ls node-v14.18.0-linux-arm64  node-v14.18.0-linux-arm64.tar.gz  node-v14.18.0-linux-arm64.tar.xz`

And then copying the files via this command `sudo cp -R * /usr/local/`
as per this article: https://www.makersupplies.sg/blogs/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-and-npm-on-the-raspberry-pi

I have rebooted and gone through the `nvm install 14` again.

Also when I run `node -v` I get this

`lharby@raspberrypi:/usr/bin $ node -v -bash: /usr/local/bin/node: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error`

And if I check the binary for node I get this:

`lharby@raspberrypi:/usr/bin $ file node node: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3, BuildID[sha1]=13d12facc999f5948728d89ae48b50cf3ed69662, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, stripped`

So it seems as though it is installed and the correct version/architecture.

I believe my Pi only has 1GB Ram.

So, am I going about this the right way? Is the Pi capable of running an app built in node v.14?

My plan is to host a nodejs app I have built and run the pi as a server. Really not sure what else to try, so I hope someone can help. NVM is not essential, so manually installing v14 should be OK for now, but of course NVM would give me more options to future proof it. TIA

Answer (score 1):

The node versions you get with nvm are not compatible with your Arm architecture of your RasberryPi.

Download the nodejs Binaries and do an installation from there.

Comment: Yeah I did some uninstalls and started again. the last version of node I found for armv6l is node 11, however my app is built on node 14, so I have to try and reverse engineer it to work with node 11. But the manual download and installation worked so that was some progress.